# Задание по ООП из книги «Программирование на Java для детей, родителей, бабушек и дедушек»

Tags: java, классы, методы, переопределение

Задание заключается в чём?
А в том, что надо:

1. Создать новый класс Сar и включить в него следующие методы:

   ```
   public void start()
   public void stop()
   public int drive(int howlong)
   ```

   Метод `drive()` должен возвращать общее расстояние используя следующую формулу для расчёта `distance = howlong*60`
2. Создать ещё один класс `CarOwner`, который будет создавать экземпляр объекта `Car` и вызывать его методы. Результат каждого такого вызова должен быть напечатан с помощью `System.out.println`.

С первым пунктом я разобрался, но со вторым вечно ошибки и проблемы.

Это задание из книги «Программирование на Java для детей, родителей, бабушек и дедушек».

P.S. Желательно дать хоть какое-то объяснение решения ибо только учусь :-)

Код:

```
public class Main {
    public class CarOwner {
        Car car = new Car();
        public int cardrive = car.drive(10);
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Car car = new Car();
            car.start();
            System.out.println("Проехали: " + car.drive(30) + " км");
            car.stop();
        }
    }
    public class Car {
        public void start() {
            System.out.println("Поехали ВИВИВИВИВИВИВ!");
        }

       public void stop() {
            System.out.println("Приехали");
        }

        public int drive(int howlong) {
           int distance = howlong * 60;
            return distance;
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибки:

> Error:(14, 23) java: non-static variable this cannot be referenced
>   from a static context
>
> Error:(13, 28) java: Illegal static declaration in inner class
>   Main.CarOwner   modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable
>   declarations

Comment: Покажите как Вы реализовали класс `CarOwner`.

Comment: `... со вторым вечно ошибки и проблемы.` думаю лучше разбираться с ошибками и проблемами по одной, ибо решений для данного задания может быть более одного.

Comment: @Sv__t , пока никак..

Comment: @defaultlocale получается, что public static void main  ругается на то что он статик, если его вставить в класс CarOwner, как показано в книге, а в других случаях, этот класс не может работать с классом Car

Comment: @OlegGenevjov пока неясно что происходит, нужно внести в вопрос (под вопросом есть кнопка «править») сам код и точный текст ошибки(-ок). Посмотрите как создать [воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @defaultlocale кривовато, но достаточно понятно..

Comment: Первая ошибка Error:(9, 34) связана с тем, что вы вызываете метод без аргументов: попробуйте передать, например, число 10: напишите `car.drive(10)` вместо `car.drive()`

Comment: @Vadik обновил, -1 ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Избавьтесь от неиспользуемых полей.

У `CarOwner` все действия выполняются в методе `main`. Поля:

```
Car car = new Car();
public int cardrive = car.drive(10);
```

не используются и обращений к ним нет. Можно их убрать.

2. Разнесите классы друг от друга

Классы `CarOwner` и `Car` зачем-то вложены в класс `Main`. Сам класс `Main` ни для чего не используется. Думаю что на данном этапе вкладывать классы в друга незачем. Тем более, что если `CarOwner` — вложенный класс, то он не может содержать статичный метод (`main`) о чем и говорит ошибка:

> Error:(13, 28) java: Illegal static declaration in inner class Main.CarOwner modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations

грубый перевод: у вложенного нестатичного класса не может быть статических методов.

Перенесите `CarOwner` в `CarOwner.java`:

```
public class CarOwner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car car = new Car();
        car.start();
        System.out.println("Проехали: " + car.drive(30) + " км");
        car.stop();
    }
}
```

В одном каталоге с ним создайте `Car.java`:

```
public class Car {
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Поехали ВИВИВИВИВИВИВ!");
    }

   public void stop() {
        System.out.println("Приехали");
    }

    public int drive(int howlong) {
       int distance = howlong * 60;
        return distance;
    }
}
```

Класс `Main` можно убрать

Первая ошибка связана с особенностями работы вложенных классов. После удаления вложения должна быть разрешена.

Answer (score 2):

Нет причин создавать вложенные классы. Если только начинаете разбираться с Java, то старайтесь придерживаться правила: 1 класс — 1 файл (причём названия класса и файла должны совпадать).

В файле `Car.java` у вас будет класс `Car`.

А в `CarOwner.java` у вас будет класс `CarOwner`.

Эти рекомендации позволят вам избежать указанных проблем.